# Invocar una función de un formulario desde otro formulario

Tags: c#, windows-forms

He estado leyendo muchas fuentes, incluso las de el buen Leandro; pero no logro entender. El problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un formulario que cuenta con un menú lateral, el cual tiene digamos el menú Catálogos... SubMenú Clientes. Al hacer clic en el botón clientes se lanza la siguiente función:

```
 //Método para abrir formularios dentro del panel contenedor.
    public void AbrirFormulario<MiForm>() where MiForm : Form, new()
    {
        Form formulario;
        formulario = PanelContenedor.Controls.OfType<MiForm>().FirstOrDefault(); //Busca en la colección el formulario
        //Si el formulario/instancia no existe
        if (formulario == null)
        {
            formulario = new MiForm();
            formulario.TopLevel = false;
            formulario.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            formulario.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            PanelContenedor.Controls.Add(formulario);
            PanelContenedor.Tag = formulario;
            formulario.Show();
            formulario.BringToFront();
            formulario.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(CerrarFormulario);
        }
        else //Si el formulario/instancia existe
        {
            formulario.BringToFront();
        }
    }
```

Como podemos observar la función abre un formulario dentro de un panel llamado PanelContenedor, creando una sola instancia, pues si se pulsara de nuevo, trae al frente el formulario. Hasta ahí perfecto, pero una vez que tienes abierto el catálogo y quiere ver el detalle de un cliente, sería repetir la misma función, pues ahora vamos a abrir un formulario encima del catalogo de clientes, pero dentro del mismo panel, (No es multiventana, se abre todo dentro del contenedor). El problema está ahí, que aunque intento algo como:

```
PRINCIPAL inicio = new PRINCIPAL();
inicio.AbrirFormularioz<frmClienteCAP>();
```

Pues no hace nada, he repasado línea por línea en el depurador y aunque pasa por todas las líneas sin errores, no parece realizar nada. En vb.net realice lo mismo y funciona perfecto, con todos los formularios que quiera, pero en C# no, solo puedo hacerlo digamos en un primer nivel.

El panel contenedor tiene la propiedad modificador en Public, al igual que el método.

Creo que el tema va por las interfaces, o por eventos invocados desde el formulario hijo. Ojalá alguien tenga el tiempo de explicarme como se realiza en C#.

ACTUALIZACIÓN

Encontré que al abrir el formulario hijo debo enviar la instancia del formulario padre para crear el enlace:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormAux form = new FormAux(this);
        form.Show();
    }
```

Ese ejemplo debería implementarlo en mi función AbrirFormulario, justo antes de formulario.show();

¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: Van 3 intentos en mi vida de migrar definitivamente a C#, pero siempre en este punto, he tirado proyectos muy avanzados a la basura para reiniciar en vb.net, y pues funciona todo perfecto ahí. Espero que puedan ayudarme...

Comment: Y porque tienes que abrir el nuevo formulario dentro de un panel, que ventajas tiene eso? No es mejor abrir el formulario como una nueva ventana?

Answer (score 0):

Para ejecutar funciones que están en otro formulario puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
FrmPrincipal frm = (FrmPrincipal)Application.OpenForms["FrmPrincipal"];
if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<FrmPrincipal>().Any())
{
    frm.EjecutarFuncion();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

mil gracias, a mi me resulto perfecto me abre el formulario dentro de otro del panel

```
public void btnModulo2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    frmPresentacionInicioPrincipal frm = (frmPresentacionInicioPrincipal)Application.OpenForms["frmPresentacionInicioPrincipal"];

        if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<frmPresentacionInicioPrincipal>().Any())
        {
            frm.AbrirFromulario(new frmControlPiso());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.